# C putting floats in a 2D array puts random values

Tags: c++

I take input from the user, calculate the number of rows and columns needed and put all the numbers in an array but it puts seemingly random values, it also duplicates some values i want to take the input from the user and put all the numbers in 2d array in order to do matrix operations

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
#define max_input_limit 99
float matrix_1[100][100];
float matrix_2[100][100];
float result[100][100];
int rows_1 = 0;
int cols_1 = 0;
void str_to_array1(char str[max_input_limit])
{
    // sample input: [1 2 3, 4 5 6, 7 8 9]
    // count number of commas
    int rows = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ',')
            rows++;
    }
    rows_1 = rows;
    // count number of spaces before first comma
    int cols = 1;
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != ','&&i<strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ')
        {
            cols++;
        }
    }
    cols_1 = cols;
    //remove all commas and brackets from str
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ',' || str[i] == '[' || str[i] == ']')
        {
            str[i] = ' ';
        }
    }

    // fill 2D array
    float arr[100][100];
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r <= rows; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            {
                if (str[i] != ' ' && str[i+1] != NULL)
                {
                    arr[r][c] = atof(&str[i]);
                    matrix_1[r][c] = arr[r][c];
                    cout << matrix_1[r][c]<<" ";
                    //if (arr[r][c] == rows+r)
                        //cout << ",";
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
void str_to_array2(char str[max_input_limit])
{
    // sample input: [1 2 3, 4 5 6, 7 8 9]

    // count number of commas
    int rows = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ',')
            rows++;
    }
    rows_1 = rows;
    // count number of spaces before first comma
    int cols = 1;
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != ','; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ')
            cols++;
    }
    cols_1 = cols;
    //remove all commas and brackets from str
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ',' || str[i] == '[' || str[i] == ']')
        {
            str[i] = ' ';
        }
    }

    // fill 2D array
    float arr2[100][100];
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r <= rows; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            {
                if (str[i] != ' ' && str[i + 1] != NULL)
                {
                    arr2[r][c] = atof(&str[i]);
                    matrix_2[r][c] = arr2[r][c];
                    cout << matrix_2[r][c]<<" ";
                    //if (arr[r][c] == rows+r)
                        //cout << ",";
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
void add(float result[100][100], float matrix_1[100][100], float matrix_2[100][100])
{
    cout << "[";
    for (int r = 0; r < rows_1; r++)
    {
        for (int c=0; c < cols_1; c++)
        {
            result[r][c] = matrix_1[r][c] + matrix_2[r][c];
            cout << result[r][c] << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << "]";
}
int main()
{
    char str[99];
    char str2[99];
    cin.getline(str, 99);
    str_to_array1(str);
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(str2, 99);
    str_to_array2(str2);
    

}
```

When i put
[1 2 33, 4 55 6]

I get output
[1 2 33 3 4 55 5 6 ]

Comment: Please only tag the language you are actually using. This looks very C-ish, but it is C++

Comment: you're reading two lines but your sample input only has one line? Please show a [mre]. Why copy and paste `str_to_array1` to `str_to_array2` rather than add a parameter so it can target a different array>